# Android inApp Confusion

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am about to implement inApp Purchases in my app, but Iam totally confused about which way to go. On Android developer site there are different aproaches, but it is not clear why there are 2?:

http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html

and

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html

Answer (score 0):

I feel for you. I found the [the tuts on this guy's blog](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/) very useful for cutting through the confusion. If you follow his process, you can, I attest, successfully implement in-app billing. I've linked to the older tutorial, I followed, but he's got a newer one as well (see the link on that page), which includes Github-hosted source code and updates to support the latest Android library changes.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/?r=5f6b7abfd0534acd5bfc7c14436f4500c99e0358) you can find TrivialDrive example app utilizing In-app Billing V3. It's sample app directly from Google.

The most important class is `IABHelper`, source code [here](https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java?r=5f6b7abfd0534acd5bfc7c14436f4500c99e0358).

The link posted by JASON G PETERSON is pointing to a deprecated version of In-app Billing V2. Here's link to the version 3: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment-v3/